# Finding files present in directory

Tags: r, loops

An analysis which I ran produced around 500 files which are named file1 to file500

However, some files in between are missing (such as file233 and file245 as well as others).  I would like to further process them in a loop in R but then I would need to filter out the files which are not present.

Is there an easy way to store the number after file in a vector in R which I can then use for the loop?

```
v<-containing all numbers after file which are present in the directory
```

Should have mentioned that the files do not have the ending .txt but are just names fileXX where the XX is the number

Comment: Another approach might be using `list.files(pattern = ".txt")` to get all .txt files in the directory.

Comment: Also consider appending zeroes to the number in the file name, i.e. `file001.txt`, `file002.txt`, etc. This makes sorting the names much easier. Look at `sprintf('%03d', 1:10)` to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to simply create a list of the files that are actually present in the directory, like @beginneR said:

```
list_of_files = list.files('/path/to/dir')

do_some_processing = function(list_element) {
    # Perform some processing and return something
}
lapply(list_of_files, do_some_processing)
```

If you need the numbers in the filename, a simple regular expression will do:

```
> grep('[0-9]', sprintf('file%d', 1:100))
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
 [19]  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
 [37]  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
 [55]  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
 [91]  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
```

Comment: the problem is that I really only need to parse out the numbers after fileXX.txt (where the number is the XX) for all the files in the dir. The files do not have the ending .txt this was just an example they are just names fileXX

Comment: Than simply exclude the `pattern` part to get all the files present, or use a different `pattern` e.g. `file*`.

Comment: but how would i then parse out the numbers? list.files will only give me a list of files?  file1, file2...file300 but I would need to grep the numbers (1,2..300)

Comment: Why do you need the numbers? You already have a list as an output of `list.files`.

Comment: I would like to store th enumbers in a vector to then run a loop . What is sprintf('file%d) what is the file%d mean?

Comment: I use `sprintf` to create a vector `c('file1', 'file2', etc)`, see the documentation of `sprintf` for more details.

Comment: i tried the code but the problem is that with the grep solution it just finds all numbers from 1 to 1200. I now have a table with the only column being fila1,file2,file3 ... how can i just grep the numbers out of these character expressions?

Comment: I already added a grep based solution to my answer some time ago,  have a look at that as it should answer your question.